# Mark migration as run in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan, artisan-migrate

My migration failed, so I just ran a query manually in MySQL Workbench.

Is there an artisan command to mark a migration as complete? So that when I run future migrations, it skips the ones I know don't need to be run.

I can list them and their status with this command and see which ones have run and not:

```
php artisan migrate:status
```

I can manually insert an entry into the database migrations table probably if no command. ( but not with a migration at the moment :P )

I suppose I could also... delete the migration.

Answer (score 17):

I've just did the following:

1. Commented out the content of `YourMigrationClass::up()` method. Like this:

   ```
   class AddSessionIdToActivitiesTable extends Migration
   {

       public function up()
       {
           /* commenting this out:
           Schema::table('activities', function (Blueprint $table) {
               $table->integer('session_id')->nullable();
           });
           */
       }
   ```
2. Run: `php artisan migrate`
3. Check it's marked as "Ran?": `php artisan migrate:status`
4. (optional) Uncomment the method's content for it to serve as documentation in your VCS.

Answer (score 7):

You wrote that you run the migration's sql directly in the database, so I assume that for you running another 2 statements would be fine too.

With laravel 5.7 (and probably some lower versions) you need to populate the migration information in the database (in the `migrations` table).

The information you need is the `migration` (the filename without the `.php` extension) and the `batch` number (to decide which migrations to run at once when rollbacking a migration for instance)

First you have to see wich the last batch number is:

```sql
SELECT MAX(batch) from migrations;
```

Let's say the above query returns `42`, then we have to insert the data with batch number `42 + 1 = 43`

Assuming that the migration that you want to mark as run is `database/migrations/2019_01_29_091850_update_jobs_table_for_laravel_5_3.php`,

to populate the information you need to run:

```sql
-- note that you should not include the .php extension
INSERT INTO migrations VALUES ("2019_01_29_091850_update_jobs_table_for_laravel_5_3", 43);
```

Then running `php artisan migrate:status` will report the migration as run.

May be you can accomplish the task with one query... I'll leave that task open for the comments from the sql experts.

Comment: A tip: you'll want to ensure that the timestamp portion of the date that's prepended to your migration name exactly matches what your migration:status shows. I made the mistake of simply using the time I saw on my migration file, which was something like 2021_07_29_150329 (prepended to "_my_migration_name"). But I kept getting status of "not run". I saw that "migration:status" was showing 2021_07_29_183341 so when I updated my table entry, the migration status then showed as "run" correctly. Apparently even that part of the name matters.

Answer (score 1):

At present (Laravel <= 5.6), There is no command to update the database to mark a migration as run. You'll just have to do so manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can always create your own artisan commands.