How to Handle Duplicate Column Error in Laravel Migration After Manually Adding Columns in Production?
One of my team members added some columns to the production database table using phpMyAdmin. Afterwards I saw that the data wasn't matching so i decided to create the migration files for the new columns. Now when I try to run php artisan migrate in the production environment I am getting duplicate column error because the columns already exist in the database. How can I handle this problem in Laravel?
I have considered removing the columns manually from the database and then running the migrations but this may result in data loss.
Is there any way to modify the migration without dropping the existing columns?

"added some columns to the production database table using phpMyAdmin" - why? That should never be done

@NicoHaase that's not my decision.

Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48958629/mark-migration-as-run-in-laravel helps, if this affects a whole migration (and not parts of it)

You could use hasColumn.
  public function up()
    {
        if (!Schema::hasColumn('table_name', 'column_name'))
        {
            Schema::table('table_name', function (Blueprint $table)
            {
                $table->string('column_name');
            });
        }
    }

More information on the document

The logic is not right. It should be !Schema::hasColumn

yeah changed it. Was manually writing in SO.

you can check in your migration file


<?php
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class AddNewColumnToMyTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('my_table_name', function (Blueprint $table) {
            if (!Schema::hasColumn('my_table_name', 'new_column')) {
                $table->string('new_column')->nullable();
            }
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('my_table_name', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('new_column');
        });
    }
}



